# How to construct a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials, roots

Given a sequence  $x_n$ whose number of limit points is finite.  How to algebraically construct a polynomial whose roots are the limit points of a given sequence? Moreover, without explicitly calculating the limit points of this sequence. What ideas can I use here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with arbitrary sequences, that is not possible. An arbitrary sequence may have infinitely many limit points and then, unless every real number is a limit point of the sequence, there is no polynomial whose set of roots is the set of the limit points of the sequence.

Comment: But if I know in advance that the number of limit points in it is finite?

Comment: That makes no sense, since you asserted that the sequence is an arbitrary one.